# R replicate function without repetition of drawn numbers

Tags: r

I'm looking for a lotto-function, meaning the drawn numbers aren't repeated. If I try either

```
y <- replicate(39,sample(1:39,1,replace=FALSE))
```

or

```
y <- replicate(39,sample(1:39,1,replace=TRUE))
```

the drawn numbers are repeating.
How can I prevent this?

Comment: Kasimir, to do what you're asking within `replicate` is over-complicating things significantly. I suggest you go the route of the answers provided. Side note: in general, `replicate(m,sample(n,size=1))` is *much* slower than `sample(n,size=m)`, and you lose the easy ability to disallow repeated values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sample(1:39, 39, replace = FALSE)`. Check `?sample`.

Comment: A little shorter, you could do `sample(39L, 39L, replace = FALSE)` for the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `replicate` for that.  To get 39 draws without repeats, use
`sample(1:39, size = 39, replace = FALSE)` (or, making use of defaults,
`sample(39)`).

Answer (score 1):

Work from the inside out.

```
sample(1:39, 1, replace = FALSE)
```

picks one number from `1:39` uniformly at random. The `replace = FALSE` serves no purpose as you are only drawing one number anyway.

Now

```
replicate(39, sample(1:39, 1, replace = FALSE))
```

just replicates that 39 times. So there's no reason to expect there to be no duplicates.

You don't say exactly what lotto game you want to simulate. But the usual one is a something like a `Lotto 6/39` game where 6 numbers are drawn from `1:39`. To do this use:

sample(1:39, 6, replace = FALSE)

If you want to simulate many plays, say 1000 of them, that's when you use `replicate`:

```
replicate(1000, sample(1:39, 6, replace = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you, so in this example you get my lotto game like 6 times, and every row of the given matrix is one posibility, right?

Comment: No need to apologize. In my example I have defined the lotto game as "pick 6 out of 39 numbers without replacement". Each *column* is one play of the game.

Comment: Great! Just tried it and notieced, that it is the columns!
So e.g. i set another variable h<-[:,1] to get one result gain, i guess.

Comment: i mean h<-[,1], or instead of 1 another number 0f 1:6